# UnicodeDecodeError reading csv file on mac but works perfectly on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, python-unicode

I am getting up some code to import a .csv file from 2 analysers, search through the summary data at the head of the file (varies between 10-50 rows) and extract the larger raw data table.

While the two analysers output files setup differently, the same principle applies - I search through the file for the top left cell of the table which is a header for the 'time' column and since the structure is standard from there I can base the extraction. My current code is:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# open csv file
with open('data store/CPET_10s.csv', 'rU') as cortex_file:
    # get file contents
    data = csv.reader(cortex_file)

    # identify start of data table
    table_start = None

    for line, row in enumerate(data):  # PROBLEM HERE ON MAC, BUT WORKS ON WINDOWS
        try:
            first_column = row[0]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        else:
            if first_column.strip() == 't':    #'t' header for time variable
                if table_start is None:
                    table_start = line
```

This code works perfectly for files from 1 analyser on my Uni PC and my MacBook.  However, for the second analyser - it works on my Uni PC, but I get the following error message on my MacBook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Braden/Dropbox/CPET_python/import_cortex.py", line 16, in <module>
    for line, row in enumerate(data):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1783: ordinal not in range(128)
```

After some searching I understand the issue looks like there is a dodgy character in the file. I searched through the .csv and found a row of:

> Temperature,,23.3�C,

I removed it, tried to run the code again, still didn't work, can't find any other characters that aren't rendering properly.

So, two questions:
1) What could be causing this issue and why is it only an issue in macOS and not on windows?
2) how can I get the code to read in the .csv file on mac?

If it helps, I've linked to the .csv file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkt972ee1ziddvk/cortex_sb.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using `csv` to read in the file instead of the `pd.read_csv` method?

Comment: I am new to coding, so the simple reason was I understood what was happening with the data, how it was structured (I've always been an excel user, so very visual) and was able to get it to work! (well initially...)  I thought if I used pd to read in the file to a dataframe that it would be messed up with all the junk at the top of the file. I did initially try `pd.read_csv` but found it difficult to get my head around - certainly open to swapping to it though if I can get it to remove all the summary info at the beginning.